# Correct place to install demostration projects?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, windows-xp, installation, windows-installer

With the new Windows 7 restrictions (well, new to Windows Vista anyways), we can no longer install demo projects to **%ProgramFilesFolder%\OurApplication\demo\** since restricted users will not be able to open and modify these projects.

Is there a "correct" place to install these files now?

The two alternatives that I am aware of would be:

1. %AppDataFolder%\OurApplication\demo\
2. %PersonalFolder%\OurApplication\demo\
   (in XP: %PersonalFolder% = My Documents)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on whether you expect multiple accounts on a single machine to access these demo files, it may be better to modify the application to read from the public read-only location, and save a writable copy to the user's documents folder. There's little reason that this part should be done by the installer.

Comment: After some discussion with colleagues we came up with basically the same conclusion.  Install the original read-only to %AppDataFolder% and copy per-user as read-write on an as-need basis.

Answer (score 1):

I'd lean towards %PersonalFolder%\OurApplication\demo\, since you're expecting users to open the files themselves.  %AppDataFolder% is intended for (writable) data that's for the app's use (e.g., game maps, etc.)